# Aptana Function Declare signature

Tags: php, ruby, aptana, aptana3

### Is there a way to autocomment a function signature in Aptana Studio 3?

For example, when I enter this trigger : /***.

It will autogenerate this :

```
/***
    @param string $test
    @param string $test2
    @return array
*/
```

for this function :

```
function test($test,$test2)
{
    return array();
}
```

Someone made a snippet that generate the whole things :

```
/***
@param
@return
*/
function functionName()
{
}
```

Here is the original snippet from https://stackoverflow.com/users/1015975/dimitar-mihaylov

```
 snippet 'Declare Function' do |s|
 s.trigger = 'docf'
 s.scope = 'source.php'
 s.expansion = '/***
* 
*
* @param   
* @return  
* @author  $6
* @copyright ' + Time.now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') + '
*/
function ${1:functionName}($2) 
{
 $0
}'
end
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mudasobwa I want to know if there is a way to autocomment function signature as mentioned in my post. I'm used to VisualStudio and it saves me a lot of time. According to my researchs, we can write snippets in ruby but I can't figure out how to get the function parameter.